# How to implement WSAAccept using .NET

Tags: c#, sockets

I don't want my TCP server to accept connection before I validate client's IP address. Just like WSAAccept allows to do it in C.
How to do it using .NET libraries?

For example this code below

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(address, port));
socket.Listen(1);
Socket sock2 = socket.Accept();

if( Validate( sock2.RemoteEndPoint ) )
{
    // do something
}
```

I don't want my server to work like that because it will show client on the other side that port is "alive".

This is what I am looking for

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(address, port));
socket.Listen(1);
Socket sock2 = socket.Accept(Validate);
```

Comment: You accept the socket, then check and immediately close it if it fails.  That's what WSAAccept does internally.

Comment: @GabeSechan I believe WSAAccept does not send any feedback to client. Is it right?

Comment: The general advice is not to use WSAAccept with SO_CONDITIONAL_ACCEPT, because it prevents the normal processes that deal with denial-of-service attacks (SYN flooding). If your concern is to hide that you are listening on a port, that's what a firewall is for.

Comment: @pindumb thank you. You are right. Still I am impressed that there is no function like WSAAccept in .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just searched the BCL for the `WSAAccept` function. This function is not being used as of .NET 4.5.

Call `WSAAccept` using PInvoke. The `Socket` class allows you to obtain the native socket handle. Unfortunately, the `Socket` class does not allow you to construct an instance from a handle. [You'll have to perform some nasty hacks to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/765449/122718)

Comment: thank you. Your suggestion works fine. But as a result I ended up using functions like "recv" (imported from ws2_32.dll) instead of pretty .NET functions. So now I am starting to think that WSAAccept is not worth it. There must a reason why Microsoft decided not to implement WSAAccept on .NET planform.